# Inserting sections in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Using `UICollectionView`'s `performBatchUpdates` method, if I have a data source that has 0 sections and then I want to create two sections, one empty, one with one time, do I first have to  call `insertSections` to create the section and then `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` or is it fine to do:

```
let indexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 1)]
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
}, completion: nil)
```

and in that scenario, will a section be implicitly created if one doesn't already exist?

Comment: Yes - that's the point of using the method. However, you need to also be implementing both `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection`, and make sure that they are updating properly to return the new totals, otherwise it'll crash.

Comment: Is that true though? I keep trying to insert the first item into a section that doesn't yet exist and it doesn't work but if I first insert a section then insert an item, it works great.

Comment: I must be mistaken then, but you have empiric evidence of how it works - then what is your actual question?

Comment: Previously I would have thought you were correct but now I have no idea.